# Ordering problem

Tags: sorting, faq

Let's look at the following example.

```
Ordering[{0, 20 Sqrt[5], 40 Sqrt[5], 20 Sqrt[5], 20 Sqrt[10]} // N]
```

gives the right answer

> ```
> {1, 2, 4, 5, 3}
> ```

but if one removes the `N`, one gets the wrong answer

```
Ordering[{0, 20 Sqrt[5], 40 Sqrt[5], 20 Sqrt[5], 20 Sqrt[10]}]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 4, 3, 5}
> ```

Is it a bug?

Comment: For a similarly confusing problem with the same origin, look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368663/nminimize-seems-to-be-on-crack/)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is probably because by default `Sort` doesn't just use numerical values, it includes structure information as well. From the doc:

> Numeric expressions are sorted by structure as well as numerical value:

```
In[1]:= Sort[{Sqrt[2], 1, 2, 1/Sqrt[2]}]

Out[1]= {1, 2, 1/Sqrt[2], Sqrt[2]}
```

> Sort by numerical value only:

```
In[2]:= Sort[{Sqrt[2], 1, 2, 1/Sqrt[2]}, Less]

Out[2]= {1/Sqrt[2], 1, Sqrt[2], 2}
```

along with the following doc:

> Sort usually orders expressions by putting shorter ones first, and then comparing parts in a depth-first manner.

gives us a hint why. If you run `TreeForm /@ {0, 20 Sqrt[5], 40 Sqrt[5], 20 Sqrt[5], 20 Sqrt[10]}`, you'll see that the last layer (`Rational`) is the same for all four `Sqrt`s. Then the next depth down is the `Power`, in which `10` is the outlier, and is greater than `5`, so will be placed last. Finally, comparing `{20, 40, 20}` will give the ordering `{1, 3, 2}`, which when put together with the original list gives you the ordering:

```
In[77]:= Ordering[{0, 20 Sqrt[5], 40 Sqrt[5], 20 Sqrt[5], 20 Sqrt[10]}]

Out[77]= {1, 2, 4, 3, 5}
```

Comment: nice explanation..

Comment: Thanks! I actually learned a bit about MMA's sorting :). Good question!

Comment: +1, one more thing I have to check when I'm using it, like the non-orthogonality of Eigenvectors with the same eigenvalue ... :|

Answer (score 19):

No, this is not a bug, and `Ordering` does not give a wrong answer.

Quoting the documentation of `Sort`,

> `Sort[list,p]` applies the function `p` to pairs of elements in list to
>   determine whether they are in order. The default function `p` is
>   `OrderedQ[{#1, #2}] &`.

As you can see, `Sort` (and `Ordering`) compares using `OrderedQ`, not `Less`.

`OrderedQ` uses a special ordering that is applicable to *any* Mathematica expressions, not just numbers.  Read about it on the doc page of [`Sort`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sort.html).

The rule I believe applies here is the following:

> `Sort` treats powers and products specially, ordering them to correspond
>   to terms in a polynomial.

This means that terms are interpreted as if they were in the form `10 var1 + 20 var2`, i.e. variables with coefficients.  The ordering is determined by the ordering of "variables" (which in your example correspond to `Sqrt[5]` and `Sqrt[10]`), and not their coefficients.  Thus the canonical ordering is `{40 Sqrt[5], 20 Sqrt[20]}` and not the reverse, because `Sqrt[5]` comes before `Sqrt[10]` in the canonical order.

The reason for doing this is that `Orderless` functions will auto-sort their arguments in the same way.  Thus if you write a polynomial, `10 y + 20 x`, it'll be ordered on the variables yielding `20 x + 10 y`.

---

So, if you want numerical expressions sorted by numerical magnitude, use

```
SortBy[list, N]
```

If you want to get the permutation that sorts them, use

```
Ordering[ N[list] ]
```

Comment: I am certain that this has been asked either here or on SO, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: I agree, it has been. I know it came up in reference to [displaying `Orderless` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4111778/198315). However, that is the only place that comes to mind off the top of my head.

Comment: @rcollyer It is another question I remembered.  It was also about why `Sort` doesn't sort by numerical value.  I wanted to link to it, but I couldn't find it.  Regarding the question you linked to, `PolynomialForm[1 + x, TraditionalOrder -> True]` is interesting.  Just like `TraditionalForm`, it changes the printing order of polynomials.

Comment: `PolynomialForm` appears to be undocumented. Although, ``?System`*Form`` does make for interesting reading.

Answer (score 1):

## `NumericalSort`

This behavior of [`Sort`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sort.html) is indeed the documented behavior. However I also find it not intuitive.

There is a function called [`NumericalSort`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericalSort.html) (as of Mathematica 11.1) which sorts the elements of a list by numerical order. It uses [`NumericalOrder`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericalOrder.html) as the ordering function i.e. `Sort[list, NumericalOrder]`.

## Examples

```
(* different results *)

         Sort[{1, -Pi}] -> {1, -Pi}
NumericalSort[{1, -Pi}] -> {-Pi, 1}

         Sort[{{1, 2}, {-Pi, 2}}] -> {{1, 2}, {-Pi, 2}}
NumericalSort[{{1, 2}, {-Pi, 2}}] -> {{-Pi, 2}, {1, 2}}


         Sort[{{"b", 2}, {Pi, 1}}] -> {{"b", 2}, {Pi, 1}}
NumericalSort[{{"b", 2}, {Pi, 1}}] -> {{Pi, 1}, {"b", 2}}


(* same results *)

         Sort[{{"b", 2}, {"a", 1}}] -> {{"a", 1}, {"b", 2}}
NumericalSort[{{"b", 2}, {"a", 1}}] -> {{"a", 1}, {"b", 2}}
```