# Simplify set-theoretic expressions

Tags: syntax

As I can get set-theoretic simplifications of expressions and corresponding Venn diagram for example

```
(((A \ B) ⋂ (A \ C)) ⋃ ((B \ A) ⋂ (B \ C))  ⋃ ((C \ A) ⋂ (C \ B)))
```

I get well as the symbols for the symmetric difference and complement

```
Symmetric Difference: A Δ B  and   '(complement)
```

Comment: Fernando, I am afraid that I do not understand your question. Could you expand it / clarify it, maybe adding an example of *Mathematica* code that you are struggling with?

Comment: I ask for help to create an algorithm that allows me to simplify expressions of the theory of sets, and also plot the corresponientes Venn diagrams.
I also ask you to tell me what commands correspond to the "symmetric difference      A Δ B " between sets and "complement of a set   '  or   ^c"

The idea is to take as input an expression with joint operations of the simplified and the draw (Venn diagrams)

Comment: Fernando, even though your question was marked as a duplicate, please consider accepting one of the answers below by clicking on the grey check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really an answer, but it was too long for a comment.

- Regarding plotting Venn diagrams, take a look at the answers to this question: [Hot to plot Venn diagrams](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2554/27951).
- For the more general question about manipulating set-theoretic expressions, it seems to me that *Mathematica* is limited to manipulating *finite* sets that can be represented as lists. In this connection, see this tutorial on [Lists as Sets](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ListsAsSets.html)). The point has been discussed before on this site: [Define a mathematical set](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5325/define-a-mathematical-set), and the answer seem mostly negative for the general case.
- Jack Coen at the Colorado School of Mines had developed some functions to use *Mathematica* for set theory that are detailed in this report: [*Mathematica* packages for Logic and Set Theory](http://cwp.mines.edu/Documents/cwpreports/cwp-108.pdf). Of course the code may need some updating since 1991...

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite it in terms of Boolean operators and use `Simplify`:

```
((a && ! b) && (a && ! c)) || ((b && ! a) && (b && ! c)) || ((c && ! a) && (c && ! b)) // Simplify

(* a \[Xor] b \[Xor] c \[Xor] (a && b && c) *)
```

The `Xor` Boolean operator corresponds to the symmetric difference set operation.

Comment: thanks for the answers to this is sufficient