# Sorting a list of points based on their euclidean distance

Tags: mathematica-online

I need to take a list of random points and then sort them from least to greatest based on their Euclidean distance from a certain point. How would I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
orig = {1, 1};
pts = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {20, 2}];
ordered = Sort[pts, Norm[#1 - orig] > Norm[#2 - orig] &]
Graphics[{PointSize[#[[1]] .01], Point@#[[2]]} & /@  Transpose[{Range@Length@pts, ordered}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Or `SortBy[..., Norm[#-orig]&]`

Answer (score 1):

```
pts = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {20, 2}];
ordered2 = pts[[Ordering[-Norm /@ (# - orig & /@ pts)]]]

ordered2 == ordered (* `ordered` from belisarius's answer *)
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Sort` with a custom ordering function forces quadratic complexity due to pairwise comparison<sup>[(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17042/121)[(2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21712/121)[(3)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28696/121)[(4)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30293/121)[(5)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39220/121)</sup> and should be avoided whenever possible.  Use `SortBy` instead, as Szabolcs comments.

```
orig = {1, 1};

pts = RandomReal[1, {50000, 2}];

Sort[pts, Norm[#1 - orig] > Norm[#2 - orig] &] // AbsoluteTiming // First

SortBy[pts, Norm[# - orig] &]                  // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 3.911224
>
> 0.011001
> ```

It is shorter to write too. :-)  `Ordering` is slightly faster still but not as convenient to use.