# Finding the two pairs in a list of pairs that minimize and maximize a given function

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I need  to declare a list of ordered pairs, and with it I need to declare a function of two variables, say `x` and `y`, and print the ordered pairs giving the maximum and the minimum value on the function.

For example, suppose the list is

```
L = {{1, 2}, {5, 3}, {9, 2}}
```

and the function is

```
2 x + y
```

With `{x, y} = {1, 2}`, I will get 4 , with `{5, 3}`, 13, and with `{9, 2}`, 20 . Then I need to print `{1, 2}` and `{9, 2}` as the result.

Can anyone help me with it please? I don't know how to write it!

Comment: You'll need `SortBy` and `Part`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the tour! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the gray triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark sign!

Answer (score 16):

```
list = {{1, 2}, {5, 3}, {9, 2}}
func = 2*#[[1]] + #[[2]] &;

Through[{MinimalBy[func], MaximalBy[func]}[list]]
```

> `{{{1, 2}}, {{9, 2}}}`

---

Some Benchmarking:

```
benchMarkResults = Transpose@Table[
    With[{riList = RandomInteger[{1, 9999999}, {Round[10^n], 2}], rn = Round[10^n]},
     {{rn, 
       Through[{MinimalBy[func], MaximalBy[func]}[riList]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First},
      {rn, 
       riList[[Ordering[func /@ riList][[{1, -1}]]]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First},
      {rn, SortBy[riList, func][[{1, -1}]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First},
      {rn, 
       SortBy[riList, {N[func@#] &}][[{1, -1}]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First},
      {rn, SortBy[riList, {N@*func}][[{1, -1}]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First},
      {rn, 
       Pick[riList, #, Alternatives @@ MinMax@#] &[Function[{x, y}, 2 x + y] @@@ riList]; 
        // AbsoluteTiming // First}}],
    {n, 0, 7, 0.2}];
```

[image: BenchmarkPlot]

The gray line indicates where `SystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> {"MapCompileLength"}]` kicks in.

Comment: Great example using operator forms of `MinimalBy` and `MaximalBy`!

Comment: The `Pick` version should be understood as a template, where applying the function to the list is done in the last `[  ]`. For illustration purpose I chose a least optimal approach (applying the function to each individual pair) that scales linearly (`"ApplyCompileLength"` is `Infinity`). For better performance one can use `Map` (autocompiles), vectorized code, compiled code, parallelized code, or a combination of these.

Answer (score 11):

[`SortBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SortBy.html) is useful.  Taking Karsten's example input:

```
list = {{1, 2}, {5, 3}, {9, 2}};
func = 2*#[[1]] + #[[2]] &;

SortBy[list, func][[{1, -1}]]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {9, 2}}
> ```

---

To make this method robust one should convert the output to explicit numbers<sup>[(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39220/121)[(2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2729/121)</sup> with [`N`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html) since e.g. `Sort[{1, Pi, 5, 9}]` evaluates to `{1, 5, 9, π}`.  Also it is more efficient to use the stable sort syntax<sup>[(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3332690)[(2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7687/121)[(3)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27323/121)[(4)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31926/121)[(5)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/116650/121)</sup>.  Therefore what I should have written:

```
SortBy[list, {N@*func}][[{1, -1}]]
```

Or as Karsten7 points out, since [`Composition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html) does not compile this is much faster on packable data:

```
SortBy[list, {N @ func @ # &}][[{1, -1}]]
```

Comment: i don't understand the last part of the third line. why does that-1 mean?

Comment: @Alucard (Or should I say Dracula?) It is a [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) specification for the last element in the list, i.e. the one that evaluated to the largest Integer.

Comment: Alucard is the son of Dracula in the castlevania lore, not dracula. Thanks for the info, so the position in a list can be even  counted  backward from the last element? i have just realized it manipulating your code

Comment: @Alucard Yes, e.g. `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}[[-2]]`.  I see from Wikipedia that it has been around since 1986 but I don't recall seeing the Castlevania series of games.  Now I know!

Comment: @Alucard, [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/86195) has a nice explanation of how indexing works in *Mathematica*.

Comment: Why not `SortBy[list, N@*func][[{1, -1}]]`?

Comment: @m_goldberg, as the Wizard notes, that form does not do stable sorting; of course, depending on the application, this may or may not be warranted.

Comment: Using `N@*func` seems to break optimizations done by `SortBy`. (Using for example `funcN = N[2*#[[1]] + #[[2]]] &;` does not have such a negative impact on the performance.)

Comment: Or using `{N@func@# &}` instead of `{N@*func}`.

Comment: @m_goldberg I added more reference links in superscript; hopefully this is clear now.

Comment: @Karsten7 I have experienced that problem before yet I also like the cleanliness of the new operator syntax.  I wish I did not have to choose.

Comment: The compiler seems to be unable to handle `Composition`. E.g.: `CompilePrint@Compile[{{x, _Real}}, Sin@*Sqrt@x]`

Comment: @Karsten7 Yes, I know.  Is there an existing Quesiton on this?  If not I think we should create one.

Comment: If you have a phrasing in mind that allows a better answer than just "It's not in the [List of compilable functions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1096/18476), go ahead, please! You'll get my up-vote.