# Sorting a list of pairs under a given function

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

If I have a list

```
p={{15/16,1/4},{3/4,13/64},{3/4,1/4},{3/16,1/64},{3/16,1/16},{0,1/64}}
```

I apply a function  `f[x_,y_]:=2 x-5 y;` on it by command  `4^3 f@@@p` so i got

```
 {40,31,16,19,4,-5}
```

I want to sort p by using f. I try this command `SortBy[p,f]` but it gives

```
{{0,1/64},{3/16,1/64},{3/16,1/16},{3/4,13/64},{3/4,1/4},{15/16,1/4}}
```

, but i need actually

```
{{0,1/64},{3/16,1/16},{3/4,1/4},{3/16,1/64},{3/4,13/64},{15/16,1/4}}
```

Please help in this sorting case, thank you in advance.

Comment: Related: [(123914)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/123914/121)

Answer (score 6):

You need to use

```
SortBy[list, Apply[f]]
```

By the way:

> `SortBy[list,  f]` sorts the elements of list in the order defined by applying 
>   `f` to each of them.

Is a little bit misleading because apply has a special meaning in *Mathematica*. `Apply` `f` at `arg` (`f @@ arg`) does something different than `f @ arg`. And the latter is what `SortBy` really does.

That is the problem of collision of common language with name choices made for basic *Mathematica* functions. To be consistent within *Wolfram Language*, but maybe less clear for a beginner, it should be:

> `SortBy[list,  f]` sorts the elements of list in the order defined by `f` composed with each of them.

As `Compose` is what that really is: [Is there a name for #1@#2&?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28778/5478)

Answer (score 5):

Just to amplify point:

```
f[x_, y_] := 2 x - 5 y;
g[{x_, y_}] := 2 x - 5 y
```

So (1. as Kub 2.redeine)

```
SortBy[p, f @@ # &]
SortBy[p, g]
```