# SortBy misbehaving?

Tags: sorting

It maybe a stupid thing in the end but I'm stuck a couple of hours now.

I have a list of 2 points on the plane and I want to get the one with the biggest second coordinate. I thought I knew how SortBy operates. For example

```
SortBy[{{a, 1/2 (2 + Sqrt[2])}, {b, 1/2 (3 + Sqrt[2])}, {c, 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[2])}}, Function[{x}, x[[2]]]]
```

gives as expected the answer

```
{{c, 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[2])}, {a, 1/2 (2 + Sqrt[2])}, {b, 1/2 (3 + Sqrt[2])}}
```

and

```
SortBy[{{a, 1/2 (2 + Sqrt[2])}, {b, 1/2 (3 + Sqrt[2])}, {c, 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[2])}}, Function[{x}, -x[[2]]]]
```

gives as an answer

```
{{b, 1/2 (3 + Sqrt[2])}, {a, 1/2 (2 + Sqrt[2])}, {c, 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[2])}}
```

which is perfectly fine.

My list is

```
{{4/13 (-9 - Sqrt[3]), 6/13 (4 - Sqrt[3])}, {4/13 (-9 + Sqrt[3]), 6/13 (4 + Sqrt[3])}}
```

and the command

```
SortBy[{{4/13 (-9 - Sqrt[3]), 6/13 (4 - Sqrt[3])}, {4/13 (-9 + Sqrt[3]), 6/13 (4 + Sqrt[3])}}, Function[{x}, x[[2]]]]
```

gives the answer

```
{{4/13 (-9 - Sqrt[3]), 6/13 (4 - Sqrt[3])}, {4/13 (-9 + Sqrt[3]), 6/13 (4 + Sqrt[3])}}
```

which is the same as the answer I get from

```
SortBy[{{4/13 (-9 - Sqrt[3]), 6/13 (4 - Sqrt[3])}, {4/13 (-9 + Sqrt[3]), 6/13 (4 + Sqrt[3])}}, Function[{x}, -x[[2]]]]
```

Can someone explain to me what's going on? This drives me crazy.

Comment: related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2729/ordering-problem

Comment: No, it's not a bug. `Sort` only sorts numerically for explicit `NumberQ` numbers. `SortBy` is doing the same, based on second elements in this example. As pointed out in responses, to get that effect one might use `N[#[[2]]]&` as a second argument to `SortBy`.

Comment: @Daniel Would you please give your attention to [(31261)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31261/121)?  Can you give me the kind of reference I am seeking?  Will the canonical ordering ever by publicly defined in a rigorous way?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I am not aware of anything beyond what is already stated in the documentation. Also can say that, even with my own idiosyncratic internal needs (e.g. in working on products-of-powers code many years ago), I really have not had felt I had to know much about what `Sort` would do. That it puts numbers first is about all I ever relied upon. Also, occasionally it might change.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know exactly why *Mathematica* is giving a wrong result, but here's a workaround:

```
SortBy[{{4/13 (-9 - Sqrt[3]), 6/13 (4 - Sqrt[3])}, {4/13 (-9 + Sqrt[3]), 6/13 (4 + Sqrt[3])}}, 
        -N @ #[[2]] &]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

That is, force *Mathematica* to sort by their numerical value.

OR you can use `Sort` instead:

```
Sort[{{4/13 (-9 - Sqrt[3]), 6/13 (4 - Sqrt[3])}, {4/13 (-9 + Sqrt[3]),
    6/13 (4 + Sqrt[3])}}, #1[[2]] > #2[[2]] &]
```

Which gives the same result.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'm convinced that this is a bug. Should I report it?

Comment: I avoid using Sort because I'm confused with the ordering function thing.

Comment: @tst, now that I've given it a second thought, it may be that since `NumberQ` gives `False` for the second element, `SortBy` is using some other canonical criterion for the sorting. So wrapping `N` around it then forces `SortBy` to sort by their numerical values. Still, I'm not convinced this should be the way to go.

Comment: It may not be what you expected or desire but it performs as documented. "Sort[list] sorts the elements of list into canonical order." Using `N` or an inequality operator in the ordering function forces the canonical order to be numeric order for your examples. Note that since lists can contain any expressions and "Sort can be used on expressions with any head, not only List" the ordering function needs to be more generic than just numeric.

Comment: @BobHanlon Out of curiosity, how else would you order things that are clearly numeric? Plus, "canonical ordering" is vague, I saw that in the documentation too.

Comment: "Sort usually orders expressions by putting shorter ones first, and then comparing parts in a depth-first manner." This might be useful if you are trying to find the "simplest" form for expressions that are numerically equivalent. The "Details" section of the documentation for `Sort` gives insight into "canonical ordering."

Comment: @BobHanlon I would agree that this is intended behaviour if it was consistent. However I gave 2 similar examples. In one it sorts numerically and in the other it doesn't.

Comment: In your last example, the list is ordered whether or not the second part of each element is negated. The relative length/complexity of the elements do not change by negating each of them. So the `SortBy` returns the same results. The element forms are all too similar to cause a difference in the ordering. However, with `list3 = {{a, 6}, {b, 6/13 (4 - Sqrt[3])}, {c, 6/13 (4 + Sqrt[3])}, {d,2}};` compare `SortBy[list3, Last]` with `SortBy[list3, -#[[2]] &]` and you will see a difference--neither sort is numeric but they are in canonical order.

Answer (score 8):

If this is a bug it runs far deeper than `SortBy`.  Since no one has yet been able to provide [a reference for the intended ordering of `Sort`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31261/121) etc. it is hard to say with certainty.  I can demonstrate that [`Sort`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sort.html), [`Ordering`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Ordering.html) and [`Order`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Order.html) all agree, even if I can't justify that result.

```
x = {6/13 (4 - Sqrt[3]), 6/13 (4 + Sqrt[3])};

Outer[#@#2 &, {Order @@ # &, Ordering, Sort}, {x, -x}, 1] // Transpose // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Observe that both the original and negated (`-x`) forms are handed the same by each of the three functions.  We can deduce that these expressions while not `SameQ` are considered "order irrelevant."  Whether or not that is intended behavior I think only the designers can say.

What *is* clearly stated is that numeric comparision is not used by default, e.g.:

```
Sort[{∞, Sqrt[2], 1, 2, -∞, 1/Sqrt[2]}]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 1/Sqrt[2], Sqrt[2], -∞, ∞}
> ```

Therefore you should use [`N`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/N.html) if you desire a numeric ranking.

Comment: As an alternative to `N` you can use inequality operators: `Sort[{\[Infinity], Sqrt[2], 1, 2, -\[Infinity], 1/Sqrt[2]}, Less]` gives `{-\[Infinity], 1/Sqrt[2], 1, Sqrt[2], 2, \[Infinity]}` and `Sort[{\[Infinity], Sqrt[2], 1, 2, -\[Infinity], 1/Sqrt[2]}, Greater]` gives `{\[Infinity], 2, Sqrt[2], 1, 1/Sqrt[2], -\[Infinity]}`

Comment: @Bob I meant that for `SortBy` one should use `N`; I don't see how one could use e.g. `Less` there.  On the other hand of course `Less` is applicable to `Sort` and [straight out of the documentation.](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sort.html#26003)