# Sort bug in Mathematica 10?

Tags: sorting

When I input

```
Sort[{-Sqrt[3],0}]
```

I get

> {0,-Sqrt[3]}

This can't be right, can it?

Comment: This is expected behaviour. See *Possible issues* in the `Sort` documentation: "Numeric expressions are sorted by structure as well as numerical value"

Comment: See also http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2729/ordering-problem

Comment: @SimonWoods Thanks for finding the duplicate; it's much more useful to mark this as such than merely closing as easily found in the documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This result is correct.

`Sort` doesn't sort by numerical value.  It simply orders expressions—any expression, whether they represent a number of something else.

Use `SortBy[..., N]` to sort by numerical value.

See the sorting rules under Details in [`Sort`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sort.html).  See also Possible Issues on the same page.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was embedding "sort" in a function that calculates a type of signature. My expression works for other numerical expressions (besides this one) and for lists of months, days-of-the-week, letters, words, etc. I can't use /N because I am using sort in this more general context. I can live with this exception. I just needed to see how broadly my function would work.  Sort[ { -1.7, 0 }  sorts "correctly" so I just thought my subject expression would also. We can close this as I don't require further improvement.