# Sort does not sort {0, -Pi/2}

Tags: sorting

Why is this list returned unchanged by `Sort`?

```
Sort[{0,-Pi/2}]
```

> {0,-Pi/2}

While this list is returned reversed?

Sort[{0,-1}]

> {-1,0}

Mathematica 11.0.0.0 MacOS

Comment: also see [(2729)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2729/142)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Wolfram Documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sort.html) says:

> `Sort` by default orders integers, rational, and approximate real numbers by their numerical values.

It also says:

> `Sort` usually orders expressions by putting shorter ones first, and then comparing parts in a depth‐first manner.

The phrase `-Pi/2` is an expression, so this second definition is applying. i.e. if we convert each expression to 'atomic'/numerical values first...

```
Sort[{0 // N, -Pi/2 // N}]
> {-1.5708, 0.}
```

... then it behaves as expected. You can force it to sort by numerical value by explicitly specifying the method used to compare entries for `Sort`ing:

```
Sort[{0, -Pi/2}, Less]
> {-Pi/2, 0}
```

Comment: This is no bug; see [Sort bug in Mathematica 10?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131578/sort-bug-in-mathematica-10).

Comment: @corey979 - Thanks, edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks to all who replied. I don't personally think Sort ought to treat -Pi/2 as anything but a number by default, but now that I understand what is going on I will just always explicitly specify a sorting method such as Less.

Comment: `SortBy[list, N]` can be used as well.