# Sort a list in a descending order

Tags: list-manipulation

Say we have a list:

```
{{1/2, -(Sqrt[3]/2)}, {1, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}, {-(1/2), Sqrt[3]/2}, {-1, 0}, {-(1/2), -(Sqrt[3]/2)}}
```

now we want to sort that list by looking at the second component of each sub list (call it y coordinate for ease), i.e. sort it s.t. y is in the descending order. So we'd get

```
{{1/2, Sqrt[3]/2},{-1/2, Sqrt[3]/2},{1,0},{-1,0},{1/2,-(Sqrt[3]/2)},{-1/2,-(Sqrt[3]/2)}}
```

And yeah, I should mention that if there are more than one sub lists with equal y, we would additionally (sub)sort them by descending x (first component in each of the sub lists).

I tried to use SortBy, in different forms, but I don't seem to be able to figure it out by myself. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: "I tried to use SortBy" What did you try, specifically?

Comment: Likely a duplicate of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2729/12

Comment: Thanks for that link @Szabolcs. `Reverse[SortBy[list, N[Last]]]` seems to be doing the job.

Comment: Not sure why and how in the case of those sub lists that have equal y component it puts those with the greater x first...

Comment: Just realized that `Reverse[SortBy[list, N[Last]]]` doesn't actually work.

Comment: Try `SortBy[list, N[-Last[#]]&]` instead.

Comment: You did not say what you tried originally. `N[Last]` is not a function, so it's not appropriate here. Use `N@*Last` or `N[Last[#]]&`.

Comment: @amator, if you've figured it out from the comments, you can answer your own question. Helps the silent majority of lurkers develop their knowledge too.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, the following works as desired:

`Reverse[SortBy[list, N[Last[#]]&]]`.

Comment: If you use `SortBy`, you might as well put a minus sign in front of the sorting function so you don't have to reverse the list after sorting it.

Comment: Nice, wasn't aware of that, thank you @SjoerdSmit !

Answer (score 1):

```
list = 
  {{1/2, -(Sqrt[3]/2)}, {1, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}, 
  {-(1/2), Sqrt[3]/2}, {-1, 0}, {-(1/2), -(Sqrt[3]/2)}};
```

Using `ReverseSortBy` (new in 12.0)

```
ReverseSortBy[N @* Last] @ list
```

{{1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}, {-1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}, {1, 0}, {-1, 0}, {1/2, -1/2 Sqrt[3]}, {-1/2, -1/2 Sqrt[3]}}

Answer (score 1):

```
l = 
  {{1/2, -(Sqrt[3]/2)}, {1, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}, 
  {-(1/2), Sqrt[3]/2}, {-1, 0}, {-(1/2), -(Sqrt[3]/2)}};
```

The ordering using `OrderingBy`:

```
o = Flatten[RotateRight[Sort /@ Partition[Reverse@OrderingBy[#, Abs], 2]]] &@l;
```

Apply the ordering:

```
l[[o]]
```

> {{-(1/2), Sqrt[3]/2}, {-(1/2), -(Sqrt[3]/2)}, {1, 0}, {-1, 0}, {1/2, -(Sqrt[3]/2)}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}}