# Find second largest elements in list

Tags: list-manipulation

Given a list:

```
lis = {37.21, 37.21, 37.2, 44, 44, 44, 101, 101}
```

What is a simple way to extract the second largest elements?

```
In[1]:= someFunction[lis]

Out[1]= {44, 44, 44}
```

Comment: As of version 13.2: `In[7]:= lis[[PositionLargest[lis, 2][[2]]]]                                     

Out[7]= {44, 44, 44}`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One way, not highly efficient:

```
lis = {37.21, 37.21, 37.2, 44, 44, 44, 101, 101};

lis ~Cases~ Union[lis][[-2]]
```

> ```
> {44, 44, 44}
> ```

This should be a bit more efficient:

```
ConstantArray @@ Sort[Tally@lis][[-2]]
```

**Caveat:** both of these methods [rely on sorting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2729/121) and therefore *require* numeric data.

---

flinty's method with refinements by both [C. E.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/731/c-e) and me:

```
Pick[lis, lis, RankedMax[DeleteDuplicates@lis, 2]]
```

This appears to be the fastest overall and it avoids the sorting issue referenced above.

---

### Benchmarking

A quick test of the methods posted so far reveals an interesting pattern.  Note that in the benchmark I use a list of a fixed length of one million and vary the number of unique elements within that list.

*Adding methods f5, f6, and f7, and a second test with unpackable data.*

Performed in *Mathematica* 10.1

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

SetOptions[Benchmark, TimeConstraint -> 30];

f1[lis_] := lis ~Cases~ Union[lis][[-2]]
f2[lis_] := ConstantArray @@ Sort[Tally@lis][[-2]]
f3[lis_] := MaximalBy[DeleteCases[lis, Max@lis], # &] (* Conor/kglr *)
f4[lis_] := Split[Sort@lis][[-2]]  (* kglr *)
f5[lis_] := Pick[lis, lis - RankedMax[DeleteDuplicates@lis, 2], 0]; (* flinty/C. E. *)
f6[lis_] := Extract[List/@KeySort[PositionIndex[lis]][[-2]]][lis] (* CA Trevillian *)
f7[lis_] := Pick[lis, lis, RankedMax[DeleteDuplicates@lis, 2]] (* flinty/C.E./me *)

BenchmarkPlot[{f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7},
  RandomInteger[#, 1*^6] &, 10^Range[6], Joined -> True]

BenchmarkPlot[{f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7},
  Prepend[0.5]@RandomInteger[#, 1*^6] &, 10^Range[6], Joined -> True]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 Using v12.1 on my Mac, the benchmarks for `f1`, `f3`, and `f4` all stop at `n == 10^5`, only `f2` goes up to `n == 10^6`. Also, the `PlotMarkers` are visible in the plot just like in the `PlotLegends`.

Comment: flinty's `DeleteDuplicates` + `RankedMax` approach appears to be competitive when used in conjunction with `Pick` to select all elements. [Benchmark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7YJy.png) - f5 is flinty's method.

Comment: @BobHanlon Try `SetOptions[BenchmarkPlot, TimeConstraint -> 30]`. I *don't* need this in version 10.1 when explicitly specifying test points, but I think that should do it.

Comment: @C.E. Benchmark updated.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - I get the error message `SetOptions::optnf : TimeConstraint is not a known option for BenchmarkPlot.` On the first plot, only `f2` and `f5` go to `10^6`. The others only go to `10^5`. On the second plot, `f2` only goes to `10^5` and the others only go to `10^4`. There appears to have been significant changes since v10.1, not all for the better.

Comment: @BobHanlon It seems that the `TimeConstraint` option is no longer passed down.  Please try `SetOptions[Benchmark, TimeConstraint -> 30]` after loading GeneralUtilities and see if that works.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - that fixed everything. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

another way...

```
MaximalBy[DeleteCases[lis, Max@lis], # &]
```

> ```
> {44, 44, 44}
> ```

Comment: shorter: `MaximalBy[DeleteCases[lis, Max@lis], # &]`?

Comment: @kglr your right. updated

Answer (score 10):

```
Split[ Sort @ lis][[-2]]
```

> ```
>  {44, 44, 44}
> ```

Also

```
Nearest[DeleteCases[Max @ #] @ #, Max @ #] & @ lis
```

> ```
> {44, 44, 44}
> ```

Answer (score 9):

Find the second largest unique element:

```
RankedMax[DeleteDuplicates@lis, 2]
```

... or alternatively:

```
Last@TakeLargest[DeleteDuplicates@lis, 2]
```

There are multiple ways to get them all:

```
Cases[lis, RankedMax[DeleteDuplicates@lis, 2]]
Cases[lis, Last@TakeLargest[DeleteDuplicates@lis, 2]]
Select[lis, # == Last@TakeLargest[DeleteDuplicates@lis, 2] &]
```

Comment: +1. It's faster to use `Pick` to get all, e.g. `Pick[lis, lis - RankedMax[DeleteDuplicates@lis, 2], 0];` The `Select` one can be sped up by using `With` to inject the sought after value into the anonymous function (but it will still be much slower than alternatives).

Comment: @C.E. This seems faster still: `Pick[lis, lis, RankedMax[DeleteDuplicates@lis, 2]]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you. I was messing around and somehow didn’t notice...

Answer (score 6):

This is probably terribly expensive compared to other methods, but I think it could be done better too, regardless...also I find it odd that `Ordering` doesn't manage for duplicated values...

```
Extract[List/@KeySort[PositionIndex[lis]][[-2]]][lis]
```

> ```
> {44, 44, 44}
> ```

You can just grab the positions directly with

```
KeySort[PositionIndex[lis]][[-2]]
```

> ```
> {4, 5, 6}
> ```

Though, I will say this is the only presented method so far that "`Extract`s" the second-largest value(s) in a list ;)

This is better to look at:

```
lis[[KeySort[PositionIndex[lis]][[-2]]]]
```

Answer (score 6):

Another solution:

```
lis // DeleteCases[#, Max@#]& // Cases[#, Max@#]&
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Select[Select[c=Sort[lis],#!=Last[c] &],#==Last[Select[c,#!=Last[c] &]]&]
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution using `Tally`, `SortBy` and `ConstanArray`:

```
ConstantArray[#[[1]], #[[2]]] &@Last@SortBy[Tally[lis], Last]

(*{44, 44, 44}*)
```

Comment: Nice. I think it's over ten this time from a quick look :-)

Comment: Thanks mate! I liked the dynamic of placing the BenchmarkPlot, I think we should implement it often :-)

Comment: I found a platform for book writing and marketing. I hope to have the opportunity to collaborate with you one day in such a project :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {37.21, 37.21, 37.2, 44, 44, 44, 101, 101};
```

Using `TakeLargestBy`

```
spl = Split @ list
```

{{37.21, 37.21}, {37.2}, {44, 44, 44}, {101, 101}}

```
n = 2;

TakeLargestBy[spl, First, n][[n]]
```

{44, 44, 44}

To also get the position (in the splitted list)

```
n = 3;

TakeLargestBy[spl -> {"Element", "Index"}, First, n][[n]]
```

{{37.21, 37.21}, 1}