# Ordering is not able to sort eigenvalues correctly!

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have a matrix as below one:

```
m={{3, 6, 11, 18, 27, 38}, {12, 18, 28, 42, 60, 82}, {33, 42, 57, 78,105, 138}, {72, 84, 104, 132, 168, 212}, {135, 150, 175, 210, 255, 310}, {228, 246, 276, 318, 372, 438}}
```

I wish to sort its eigenvectors corresponded eignevalues. For this purpose, I have explored the command:

```
{eva, evec} = Eigensystem[m];
{eva, evec} = {eva[[#]], evec[[#]]} &@Ordering[eva];
```

I believe the result is not what I expected!!!
Because:

```
{eva, evec} // N={{0., 0., 0., 0., -63.8564,  966.856}, {{32., -35., 0., 0., 0., 3.}, {7., -8., 0., 0., 1.,    0.}, {4., -5., 0., 1., 0., 0.}, {5., -8., 3., 0., 0.,   0.}, {-0.321102, -0.558587, -0.628836, -0.448233, 0.0668395,  1.}, {0.0711021, 0.158587, 0.278836, 0.448233, 0.683161, 1.}}};
```

I had anticipated that I would be able to attain

```
{-63.8564, 0., 0., 0., 0., 966.856}
```

and not

```
{0., 0., 0., 0., -63.8564,  966.856}
```

for sorted eigenvalues!!!

Where is the problem? Is there any other code to sort eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors of a matrix?

Comment: MAthematica sorts differently than you expect when the numbers are exact.  Try `Transpose@SortBy[Transpose@Eigensystem[m], N@*First] // N` do it it all in one go.

Comment: For instance, compare `Sort[{Sqrt[2], -Sqrt[2], 1, -1}]` to `Sort[{Sqrt[2], -Sqrt[2], 1, -1} // N]`.

Comment: Note: this is in the "Possible Issues" section of the `Sort` documentation.

Comment: This really should probably have been marked a duplicate of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2729/ordering-problem

Comment: Try replacing `Ordering[eva]` by `Ordering[N@eva]`.

Comment: @march, thank you so much for your comments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{eva, evec} = Eigensystem[m] // Transpose // NumericalSort // Transpose;

eva // N
(*    {-63.8564, 0., 0., 0., 0., 966.856}    *)
```

Comment: Thank you @Roman

Comment: You helped me very well.